# Docker tutorial, localhost:4000 is inaccessible

Tags: docker

Following the tutorial on https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/.

I start my docker container with `docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello`

and see

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8088/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But it's inaccessible from the expected path of localhost:4000.

```
$ curl http://localhost:4000/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:4000/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4000: Connection refused
```

Okay, so maybe it's not on my local host. Getting the container ID I retrieve the IP with 
`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 7e5bace5f69c`

and it returns `172.17.0.2` but no luck! `curl` continues to give the same responses. I can confirm something is running on `4000`....

```
 lsof -i :4000
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 94812 travis   18u  IPv6 0x7516cbae76f408b5      0t0  TCP *:terabase (LISTEN)
```

I'm pulling my hair out on this. I've read through the troubleshooting guide and can confirm
 * not on a proxy
 * don't use a custom dns
 * I'm having issues connecting to docker, not docker connecting to my pip server.

Running the app.py with `python app.py` the server starts and I'm able to hit it. What am I missing?

Comment: it should be `-p 4000:8088`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you accidentally put port=8088 at the bottom of your app.py file?  When you are running this the last line of your output is saying that your python app is exposed on port 8088 not 80.

To confirm you can run either modify the app.py file and rebuild the image, or alternatively you could run: `docker run -p 4000:8088 friendlyhello` which would map your local port 4000 to 8088 in the container.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it using:

```
docker run -p 4000:8088 friendlyhello
```

As you can see from the logs, your app starts on port `8088`, but you connect `4000` to `80` where on `80`, nothing is actually listening.

Comment: Thank you! So `-p 4000:8088` connects my local port 4000 to the docker 8088 port.